# JSF and basic authentification

Tags: java, jsf-2, servlet-2.5

i have an application with basic form authentification, all work fine (i m using servlet 2.5 and JSF2).

i need to add an extra parameter in my form (infogerant) in hidden:

```
<h:inputHidden id="infogerant" value="true" /> 
<h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username: "/> 
<h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" /> 
<h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password: "/> 
<h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true" /> 
<f:facet name="footer"> 
     <h:commandButton value="Login" type="submit"/> 
</f:facet>
```

i try to create a loginBean with a login method but my httpservletrequest don't have login method (i think only in servlet 3?)

i try to create a Filter and when i do request.getParameter("infogerant") it is null :(

how can i add an extra parameter in basic form authentification with servklet 2.5 and JSF2?

thanks a lot